# Save ggplot with twice with different file formats with ggsave (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

Is there a way to save a ggplot twice to different file formats with just one ggsave command? E.g. plot.pdf and plot.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `mapply()` in this way:

```
#Code
mapply(function(x) ggsave(x,plot = Yourplot,width = 25, height = 18, units = 'cm'),
       x=c('plot.pdf','plot.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
map(c('plot.pdf', 'plot.png'), ~ ggsave(.x, plot = Yourplot, width = 25,
             height = 18, units = 'cm'))
```